# Error converting PDF to PNG Imagemagick: unable to create temporary file

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have written a `php` script to programmatically create a `PNG` thumbnail for every `PDF` in a folder. I use `imagemagick` to do it, executing the following command:

```
exec('convert file.pdf[0] file.png');
```

Everything was working but suddenly I've started to get an error every time I try:

> convert: unable to create temporary file `file.pdf`: ӓ?U|SvU?T???[U @
>   error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/381. convert: missing an image filename
>   `file.png` @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.

Of course, I've tried directly in the command line and the same happens.

Any idea?

PS: I´m working with ImageMagick 6.6.0-4

Comment: What is the `[0]` doing in the filename of the command to be executed?

Comment: It´s to convert only the first page of the pdf file. But it has nothing to do with the issue. The same happens if I try without it

Answer (score 0):

I´ve seen that the temp directory is full of files previously created by imagemagick. I don´t know the reason why they are still there. But if i delete them, everything starts to work again.